# WSO2 ESB Magento connector

Tags: magento, wso2-esb

Need to post data to the Magento SOAP API from my WSO2 ESB REST services.
Could you please any body explain how to achieve this functionality.
I followed the below link from wso2 esb but not able to download the connector.
But not sure whether the connector will be use full or not and what is the use of [this connector](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESBCONNECTORS/Magento+Connector).

Comment: Moved the URL into a link to make the text cleaner

Answer (score 0):

All WSO2 connectors can be downloaded from [here](https://storepreview.wso2.com/store/). The Magento connector allows to access Magento SOAP API thorough WSO2 ESB. Please follow the [documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESBCONNECTORS/Working+with+Cart+Customers+in+Magento) for the connector's configuration.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of ESB connector is to integrate specific API with ESB flow easily. In this case you need to integrate Magento API. You can clone [esb-connectors repository](https://github.com/wso2-dev/esb-connectors/tree/master/magento/magento-connector/magento-connector-1.0.0) and build magento connector with maven and upload the built connector file to ESB. In order to make sure weather it is useful for you, just check your required operations are available in connector [resources and operations](https://github.com/wso2-dev/esb-connectors/tree/master/magento/magento-connector/magento-connector-1.0.0/org.wso2.carbon.connector/src/main/resources)